# Can't access IR video stream on mini camera

Tags: video, camera, streaming, v4l

I bought a "IR capable" camera (https://er-estavel.com/product/1080p-hd-mini-kamera) but I can't get the IR part to work on Linux (current Archlinux).

`v4l2-ctl --list-devices` gets me:

```
GENERAL - UVC : GENERAL - UVC  (usb-0000:00:14.0-1):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media1
```

I can show the video of the camera via: `mpv av://v4l2:/dev/video2` but in the dark it simply shows black (the camera is supposed to switch to IR in the dark - but I figured it might not do that automatically and maybe `/dev/video3` is the IR video stream? Is that possible?

If so, it doesn't work, because `mpv av://v4l2:/dev/video3` only shows errors:

```
[ffmpeg/demuxer] video4linux2,v4l2: ioctl(VIDIOC_G_INPUT): Inappropriate ioctl for device
[lavf] avformat_open_input() failed
Failed to recognize file format.

Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
```

Any ideas how I can get the IR video?

Comment: Some cheap cameras only send IR data when the environment is dark, using the regular stream.

Comment: I think this one is supposed to do that as well, but it doesn't - it could also be that it's broken? But why would there be the other video device then?

Comment: What happens to the video stream when you surround the camera with darkness?

Comment: "Night Vision" (from the web site) and "IR capable" are not the same. "Night Vision" seems to mean the camera sensor is sensitive to visible and IR light. When "Night" occurs the visible light goes away, and the camera's Automatic Gain Control turns up the IR. The camera MAY turn on IR LEDs for illumination. No separate IR stream.

Comment: Use `lusb -v` Read `man lsusb`.

Comment: @waltinator Then what's "IR capable"?